# How to print dictionary values line by line in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

This is my dictionary

```
 {'www.pic2fly.com/Weather+Of+Bahawalpur.html': ['https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?
 id=OIP.RsEykDoK1xxg2zivHYW7WwEsC5&pid=Api'], 'panoramio.com/photo/84118355': 
 ['https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.1683LeSgJHoFhxX-tKhGSAEsDh&pid=Api'], 'nativepakistan.com/photos-of-bahawalpur': ['https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.wS0pep46eEsGSSY39RNxLQEsDQ&pid=Api', 'https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Zn5zIzevX8HqUnwCyRZ3QwEsDJ&pid=Api', 'https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.671-BIumri8_oRAQRLd-ggEsDJ&pid=Api', 'https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.0dShzaFVWKBtTSxnOFHyaAEsDI&pid=Api', 'https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.LXLVj2t-dawxlMcJp1GBTAEsDV&pid=Api', 'https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Z0-Y7RzbFM43N6YFNevsTQEsDL&pid=Api', 'https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.AYjL8nxCNUE-HvEiifvqWQEsCc&pid=Api', 'https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Iy9NYKksUM3TSpgmOc0-JgDZEs&pid=Api', 'https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.NHdCNr5g2CYn3L6wP77BygEsDg&pid=Api']}
```

Using for loop I print values like this this

```
for key in res.iterkeys():
  print key

for value in res.itervalues():
  print value
```

I need this  as output

```
www.pic2fly.com/Weather+Of+Bahawalpur.html

https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.wS0pep46eEsGSSY39RNxLQEsDQ&pid=Api 

panoramio.com/photo/84118355

https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.Zn5zIzevX8HqUnwCyRZ3QwEsDJ&pid=Api 

nativepakistan.com/photos-of-bahawalpur

https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.671-BIumri8_oRAQRLd-ggEsDJ&pid=Api 
https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.0dShzaFVWKBtTSxnOFHyaAEsDI&pid=Api 
https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.LXLVj2t-dawxlMcJp1GBTAEsDV&pid=Api 
....
```

I just started learning dictionary please help

Answer (score 2):

```
# iterate the dictionary with the key and val at the same time
for key, val in res.items():
    # print the key
    print key
    for x in val:
    # iterate the list of the val and print all items
        print x
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print all the values in a dictionary where the values are lists. The way we do this is:

```
for key in my_dict:
    print key
    for list_value in my_dict[key]:
        print list_value
```

1. Iterate over the keys in the dictionary
2. Print the key
3. Iterate over the list found at `my_dict[key]`
4. Print each of those values.

Comment: i would use 'for key in my_dict.keys()' but guess not much difference

Comment: That definitely could help the readability! Another option is using `for key, value in my_dict.iteritems()`. I always struggle to decide which one is the right one, I guess it all depends on the situation!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you call your dictionnary a you can do:

```
for i in a:
    print(i)
    for j in a[i]:
        print(j)
```

if you are using python 2.X you can remove parenthesis with the print

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input to the dictionary is `key:[list of values]`. Below code should be able to achieve what you are looking for -

```
dictionary = {'a': [1,2], 'b': [3,4], 'c':[5,6,7,8]}
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    print(key, ':', value)
```

The output will be (the keys will be printed at no particular sequence) -

```
b : [3, 4]
c : [5, 6, 7, 8]
a : [1, 2]
```